# Adding rows to a swift array of my Schedule from a Detail View Controller won't work

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, xcode6.3.2

I have a list of events where each of them pass in data to a detail VC with an object from a core data model. For example, an `Event` can have a title, date, room, isFavorite, etc. Now, from the `DetailVC`, I have an "Add to my Schedule" button to let a user select their favorite event to attend. Once clicked, I would like to save this object to an array.

I get the this error1:

> Cannot invoke append with an argument list of type String.

**Detail View Controller:**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

    //    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //create a new array to hold on favorite objects (sessions add it to My Schedule)
    var favesArray = [Event]()

    var detailItem: Event!
```

**This is the Detail View Controller `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == Sections.info && indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell: TitleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("faveCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TitleCell

        if detailItem.isFavorite.boolValue {
            cell.valueFaveButton.setTitle("Remove from My Schedule", forState: .Normal)
        } else {
            cell.valueFaveButton.setTitle("Add to My Schedule", forState: .Normal)
        }

        cell.valueFaveButton.addTarget(self, action: "myScheduleButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell

    } else if indexPath.section == Sections.info && indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cell: TitleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TitleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TitleCell

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(detailItem!.date)

        cell.titleLabel.text = detailItem?.title
        cell.fieldLabel.text = dateString

        return cell

    } else if indexPath.section == Sections.info && indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cell: RemoveFaveCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("removeFaveCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RemoveFaveCell

        cell.removeFaveButton.addTarget(self, action: "removeFavoriteButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell

    } else if indexPath.section == Sections.description {

        let cell: LabelCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("labelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LabelCell

        cell.labelDescriptionField.text = "Swift is the new language from Apple."

        return cell
    } else {

        assertionFailure("Unhandled session table view section")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        return cell
    }
}

    func myScheduleButton(sender: UIButton) {


      detailItem.isFavorite = !detailItem.isFavorite.boolValue

      tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: Sections.info), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

        //now add this clicked/save object(event row) over the faves array


        //1 yellow warning in next line:Conditional Cast from Event to  Event always succeeds. But it compiles fine.
        if let faveSession:Event = detailItem as? Event {

            self.favesArray.append(faveSession)
        }


    }
```

Can't figure this out yet. Is this a valid approach to work with core data object to be saved later as new arrays? In my case, this will be shown when a segment button called My Schedule is pressed. Thank you for your answers.

Event.swift

```js
class Event: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var date: NSDate
    @NSManaged var isFavorite: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var timeStamp: NSDate
    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var classSelected: String
    @NSManaged var desc: String
    
}
```

Display My Schedule (favesArray objects selected in detailVC)

```js
@IBAction func FilterHSClassesByPeriod(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let classSelected: String?
        
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            classSelected = "Period 1"
        }else {
            classSelected = "My Schedule"
        }        
      
        let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "classSelected = %@", classSelected!)
        var request: NSFetchRequest = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest
        
        request.predicate = filterPredicate        
      
        var e: NSError? = nil
        
        self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&e)        
       
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define favesArray as an array of Event:

```
var favesArray = [Event]()
```

But you are trying to append a String

```
if let faveSession:String = detailItem.title as? String {
  self.favesArray.append(faveSession) 
}
```

If you want to be able to append Event and String you need to change your declaration to be:

```
var favesArray = [AnyObject]()
```

Or (if possible) cast your faveSession to Event instead String, but just you can decide if it is possible

```
if let faveSession:Event = detailItem.title as? Event {
  self.favesArray.append(faveSession) 
}
```

Comment: Right, now I properly cast it as Event, but I get warning and build fails. See changed code.

Comment: Like I said you can cast "If possible" it seems that your variable Event cannot be cast as a String. Can you post the declaration of Event?

Comment: I'm posting it right now. Now, it seems it let me cast it as Event, after an hour by changing the first declaration of the previous code. Now, once I have this array with favorites objects, how do call favesArray in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method that belongs to the master VC? Because this array is declared in the detailVC. Do I need to create a Swift class with a class function? See code updated.

Comment: Event is a NSManagedObject you shouldn't even been try to put this two in the same array. You need to re think a little you code, why are you casting  detailItem.title as Event? Would be better if let faveSession:Event = detailItem? Event { self.favesArray.append(faveSession:Event )}

Comment: Again this from from what I can see!

Comment: I can't post images just yet, but it's a segmentedControl where will be adding more tabs in the future. The important one is "My Schedule" tab displaying all the selected/favorited events. ALso, just updated code where I append the items over array.

Comment: Thinking about the code. I'm going to do create a singleton class to work with favorites that way I can call it from any other view controller class. I think, this would be one way to get going to let users add events to their schedule.